# Java Binary Search Tree Not Printing at run time

Tags: java, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have created a Binary Search Tree class which I followed some youtube videos to make. The problem is that, from what I can tell, my code is exactly the same as is in the guide I followed. The issue is that when I run my `main()` method nothing happens. There is no compile or runtime errors, the program simply does nothing. What should happen is that it should use the `toString()` method to print out some keys and values of those keys if I use the traverse methods, or it should provide a value of a node if I use the `findNode()` method. I was hoping someone could check my code to see if they can spot any logic errors and such, as I have spent a long time checking and rechecking my code and I cant seem to spot it.

Here is the code for my main method:

```
public class BinarySearchTreeAss2 {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BinarySearchTree myTree = new BinarySearchTree();

        myTree.addNode(50, 1);
        myTree.addNode(25, 2);
        myTree.addNode(15, 3);
        myTree.addNode(30, 4);
        myTree.addNode(75, 5);
        myTree.addNode(80, 6);

        myTree.inOrderTraversal(myTree.root);
        System.out.println("\n\n");

        myTree.preOrderTraversal(myTree.root);
        System.out.println("\n\n");

        myTree.postOrderTraversal(myTree.root);
        System.out.println(myTree.findNode(30));
    }
}
```

And the code for the Binary Search Tree class:

```
public class BinarySearchTree {
    Node root;

    public void addNode(int key, int value) {
        Node newNode = new Node(key, value);
        if(root == null) {
            root = newNode;
        } else {
            Node focusNode = root;
            Node parent;
            while(true) {
                parent = focusNode;
                if(key < focusNode.key) {
                    focusNode = focusNode.leftChild;
                    if(focusNode == null) {
                        parent.leftChild = newNode;
                        return;
                    } else {
                        focusNode = focusNode.rightChild;
                        if(focusNode == null) {
                            parent.rightChild = newNode;
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void inOrderTraversal(Node focusNode) {
        if(focusNode != null) {
            inOrderTraversal(focusNode.leftChild);
            System.out.println(focusNode);
            inOrderTraversal(focusNode.rightChild);
        }
    }

    public void preOrderTraversal(Node focusNode) {
        if(focusNode != null) {
            System.out.println(focusNode);
            preOrderTraversal(focusNode.leftChild);
            preOrderTraversal(focusNode.rightChild);
        }
    }

    public void postOrderTraversal(Node focusNode) {
        if(focusNode != null) {
            postOrderTraversal(focusNode.leftChild);
            postOrderTraversal(focusNode.rightChild);
            System.out.println(focusNode);
        }
    }

    public Node findNode(int key) {
        Node focusNode = root;
        while(focusNode.key != key) {
            if(key < focusNode.key) {
                focusNode = focusNode.leftChild;
            } else {
                focusNode = focusNode.rightChild;
            }
            if(focusNode == null) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return focusNode;
    }
}

class Node {
    int key;
    int value;

    Node leftChild;
    Node rightChild;

    Node(int key, int value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return value + " has the key " + key;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You messed up on the if statement brace which causes the program to go into an infinite loop.

```
if (key < focusNode.key) {
    focusNode = focusNode.leftChild;

    if (focusNode == null) {
        parent.leftChild = newNode;
        return;
    }

    else {
        focusNode = focusNode.rightChild;

        if (focusNode == null) {
            parent.rightChild = newNode;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

If the key is less than the focusNode.key then go left, ELSE go to the right, so it should really be

```
if (key < focusNode.key) {
    focusNode = focusNode.leftChild;

    if (focusNode == null) {
        parent.leftChild = newNode;
        return;
    }
} else {
    focusNode = focusNode.rightChild;

    if (focusNode == null) {
        parent.rightChild = newNode;
        return;
    }
}
```